# Excel DAX- if cell contains one of two wildcard strings

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a powerpivot data model with the column [X.Description] which may or may not contain "New Account 1234 Added" or "Account Created". The "1234" in the first part is variable.

I'd like to create a column that returns "New Account" if either string appears. Right now I have:

=if(iserror(search("New Account *added",[X.Description])),"Normal","New Account")

but it doesn't account for the "Account Created" criterion. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=if(and(iserror(search("New Account * added",[X.Description])),iserror(search("Account Created",[X.Description]))),"Normal","New Account")
```